# How to get boostrap-datepicker to work in my ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am pretty new to this whole angularjs thing and am having some trouble solving an issue. So we have a single page app that loads each page in an ng-view i have a directive that actually loads the date picker code into the view. When the page first loads it is fine but if I click to another page and then click back to the "add" page it gives me an error that says "Error: $(...).datepicker is not a function". I'm not sure if it's a jquery issue or what.

Here is my code:

index.html (towards the middle of the page is the ng-view where the views get loaded)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rx Pricing Maintenance</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.standalone.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap-dialog.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/DataTables-1.10.5-dist/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <!-- External Sources -->
    <script src="resources/jquery-2.1.3-dist/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/angular-1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/angular-1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/angular-1.3.15/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/DataTables-1.10.5-dist/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/angular-datatables-dist/angular-datatables.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/angular-datatables-dist/vendor/datatables-columnfilter/js/dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/angular-datatables-dist/columnfilter/angular-datatables.columnfilter.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Internal Sources -->
    <script src="resources/js/serviceCaller.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/js/application.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/alasql/alasql.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/alasql/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/alasql/alasql.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="pricingApp" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav><nav>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <footer>
            <div class="footer-container">

            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- end footer -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

application.js

```
'use strict';
/* App Module */

var pricingApp = angular.module('pricingApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'pricingControllers'
]);

pricingApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'views/home.html'
    }).when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'views/home.html'
    }).when('/add', {
        templateUrl : 'views/add.html',
        controller : 'SchedulesController'
    }).when('/help', {
        templateUrl : 'views/help.html',
        controller : 'VersionController'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
} ]);

pricingApp.directive('myDatePicker',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/dates.html',
    controller: function($scope){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#startDatePicker')
                .datepicker({
                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    autoclose: true
            });
            $('#endDatePicker')
                .datepicker({
                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    autoclose: true
            });
        });
    }
  }
});
```

add.html

```
<div class="main-container shadow-effect insert-tab">
<h2>Insert a New Pricing Schedule</h2>
<div>
         <form class="form-inline" name="pricingInsertForm"
        ng-submit="submitData()" role="form" novalidate >
               <my-date-picker></my-date-picker>
         </form>
     </div>
```

I have left a lot of the filler code out but this is basically how it works. So When I load the application from localhost on the add view it works fine. But when I click off the add view to the home view or something like that and go back to the add view I get the error.

I want to know what is causing the datepicker not a function error and what I can do to fix it. Thanks in advance!